# Cross browser support for angular 'ui-select module'

Tags: angularjs

This below code is correctly working in IE and Chrome browser but in Firefox the drop-down list is not coming.

```
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="cntrl">
        <ui-select ng-model="employee.select" style="width: 300px;" theme="bootstrap">
            <ui-select-match placeholder="Select a name..">
                {{$select.selected.name}}
            </ui-select-match>
            <ui-select-choices repeat="e in employees | filter {name:$select.search}" >
                <span ng-bind="e.name"> </span> <br/> 
                <span ng-bind="e.email"> </span> 
            </ui-select-choices>
        </ui-select>    
    </div>  

    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js" ></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-ui-select/dist/select.min.js" > </script>
    <script> angular.module('app', ['ui.select']).
    controller('cntrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.employee= {};

    $scope.employees=[
        {name:'ABC',email:'abc@abc.com'},
        {name:'XYZ',email:'xyz@abc.com'},
        {name:'LMN',email:'lmn@abc.com'},
        {name:'AZW',email:'azw@abc.com'},
        {name:'XWQ',email:'xwq@abc.com'},
        {name:'PQR',email:'pqr@pqr.com'}
    ];
}])
 </script>
```